# Directive input binding when using Angular HostDirectives

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular15

Using Angular 15+ [hostDirectives](https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api#adding-directives-to-a-component), how can I bind to inputs of the directive?

Note that I don't want to **forward** directive inputs to the host component, making them inputs of the component. I want to bind an expression to one of the directive inputs.

```
@Directive({
  standalone: true,
})
class MyDirective {
  @Input()
  directiveInput?: string;
}


@Component({
  hostDirectives: [ MyDirective ],
  host: {
    '[directiveInput]': 'inputValue' // This won't work, even if `directiveInput` is defined in the inputs of host directive definition object.
  }
})
class MyComponent {

  inputValue: string;
}
```

I sure can inject the directive, and assign the input manually in ngOnInit. But:

- It would be nicer to avoid imperative assignment of the input, and have the same declarative way of binding to inputs, regardless of directive being used in template or in hostDirectives
- If the value is not static but an expression, one needs to update the directive input every time the result of the expression is changed.

Comment: I think you need to inject the `MyDirective` in the `MyComponent` and set it from there

Answer (score 4):

I'll quote one of the member of the angular team [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50700#issuecomment-1590896233):

> The composing directive can not provide values to host directive
> inputs.